# How to view some statistics for certain period of Time

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-apex

Now I want to see some values like total wait time, total physical reads ,logical read, Disk Activity and Input-Output, total sort done for query for some specific time like 9.00 AM to 10.00 AM so I can estimate the situation of the Database.

How to find current memory status?

And how can i monitoring user activity also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to view some dynamic performance view like v$sysstat,V$session for your day to day activity
plz go to web and search "dynamic performance view"
i hope you understand

Answer (score 0):

Can you please specify which database version you are using and if you have standard edition or enterprise edition?

I think you can get most of the infos from Oracle Enterprise Manager Database Control e.g. for 11g.

Here are some Infos from oracle:
[Getting Started with Database Administration](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E25054_01/server.1111/e10897/em_manage.htm)

Comment: To use oracle 11g2 SE and performance tab is disable so i confused